# SQL trigger to check customer age not working

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to add a constraint to cust_birthdate, make sure the customer is more than 18 years old.

Here is my create table statement

```
create table customer(
    cust_id             char(5)    NOT NULL,
    cust_name           varchar(30),
    cust_birthdate      date,
primary key(cust_id)
);
```

I found out cannot use SYSDATE in constraint, but I found a trigger online that fit my situation.

Here is the trigger I modified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgCustomer
  BEFORE INSERT ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF(ADD_MONTHS(:new.cust_birthdate, 18 * 12) < sysdate ) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Customer must be at least 18 years old.' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

However, the trigger will not work when I insert something like this:

```
insert into customer values('C0001', 'Chek Wei', TO_DATE('20-OCT-2016', 'dd-MON-yyyy'));
```

The 'Chek Wei' customer is less than 18 years old, but no error message is shown.

I do not yet learn trigger but I since I cannot use SYSDATE on constraint, I have no choice.

What's wrong with my trigger?

I am using Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Putting business logic in the database like that is bad practice and is not recommended.

Comment: isn't that logic reversed? you want only when you add 18 years to that date is GREATER than sysdate to fire the error......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that logic reversed? you want only when you add 18 years to that date is 
GREATER than sysdate to fire the error......

There you go.... :)